# How to check table if it has rows with given nonclustered index?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write where clause for combined non-clustered unique index.
Let me explain: I created a unique non-clustered index combination of two columns and I need to check before adding new data for the appropriate table. If the table doesn't have a row with this index it should add this data, if this data exists it should be updated.
Unique non-clustered index : IX_FirstName_LastName.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Person_AddUpdate] 
@firstName nvarchar(50),
@lastName nvarchar(50),
@age int 
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Person WHERE ...)
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO Person (FirstName,LastName,Age)
     VALUES (@firstName, @lastName,@age);
END
ELSE
  UPDATE Person
  SET Age = @age
  WHERE ...
END
END
```

Comment: Um, using a `WHERE` clause? Please show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ...`? Is the index itself filtered?

Comment: I need to fill '...' with checking for non-clustered index existing

Comment: `where Firstname = @Firstname and Lastname = @Lastname`?

Comment: will this check uniqueness of them?

Comment: I think you have a misconception here: the unique index *enforces* the uniqueness i.e. there can be no such duplicate rows in the table. By the way, you may want to look at this article by [Aaron Bertrand: Please stop using this UPSERT anti-pattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern)

Comment: Yes a unique index will check uniqueness and throw an error if you try and insert a duplicate. You should really try it and see. In answer to your question, the `where` should be `where firstname=@firstname and lastname=@lastname`. But you should really read the link in the prior comment.